# Nested classes and good practices

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I'm considering using nested classes in my class. I have a class called `ServerConfiguration` and I have two classes closely related to it: a builder and a provider.

All of the classes are in separate places:

- `hosting.core.server.ServerConfiguration`
- `hosting.core.server.server_configuration.Provider`
- `hosting.core.server.server_configuration.Builder`

the question is if should I add them as nested (static) classes to the `ServerConfiguration` or keep it as is?

The `ServerConfiguration` class is very simple and adding 2 extra classes will make it more complicated.
On the other hand, it's more readable to me to have code

```
private ServerConfiguration.Builder getBuilder()
    {
        return new ServerConfiguration.Builder();
    }
```

instead of

```
private Builder getBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }
```

what do you think?

Comment: Altough your question is primarily opinion based, you should use `static` inner classes if the objects **can** exist without the superclass and inner classes if they **cannot** exist without the superclass. In the end, it is always good to put the Builder inside the class to be build (`static` class, since you need a Builder before you have an object of the class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go ahead with making the class as inner class.

As per effective java

> If a package-private top-level class or interface is used by only one class,
>   consider making the top-level class a private static nested class of the sole
>   class that uses it (Item 24). This reduces its accessibility from all the classes
>   in its package to the one class that uses it. But it is far more important to
>   reduce the accessibility of a gratuitously public class than of a package private
>   top-level class: the public class is part of the package’s API.